# How to skip pages using the browser's back button in spring webflow?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

I'm working on a project where we are requesting data from an external source, and using data from the response.

The webservice call to the external source is in a view state (lets say viewstate1) that will transition to another view state (viewstate2) when the data from the external source is receieved. This all works great, but if the user hits the browser's back button, they will return to the external source without credentials.

I want to find a way to transition back to the start of viewstate1 when the user hits the browser's back arrow from viewstate2.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove items from your back-button history with History API, but that's only possible from within a single page load. If you need to remove an external source from your history, you're out of luck.